# Background Color not applied at all tab bars on TabbedPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Using a TabbedPage control, I have 3 tabs. The BarBackground color is set in both code and xaml. However, when a user tabs to only one of the three tabs, the tabbedpage colors revert to device defaults.

I have tested this thoroughly. If I remove all ContentPage content from the tabbed page in question, the correct tab bar color appears. If I add any control (such as an empty stacklayout) the background of the tab bar messes up again.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if I make the background color of ContentPage the same as the BarBackgroundColor of the TabbedPage, all works as it should.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Example_Mobile.Views.ClosedPage"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
             x:Name="BrowseItemsPage"
             BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Theme-Secondary-BackgroundColor}">
```